Wpf Listview Template only display Namespace.ClassName
I'm working with a WPF ListView and trying to use a custom ControlTemplate to style each ListViewItem. However, when I apply the template, the ListView only displays the class name (e.g., Namespace.ClassName) instead of the actual property values bound in my data source. Removing the Template allows the ListView to display the data correctly.How can I use a Template with a ListView and still display correctly values ?
image
XAML:
            <ListView x:Name="lvFolders" Background="#1f222b" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>                        
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FolderName}" Width="200" />                      
                        <GridViewColumn Header="CreationTime" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CreationTime, StringFormat='yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'}" Width="200" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

Style:
       <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
           <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                       <Border Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="5">                   

                           <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                       </Border>
                       
                       <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                            
                           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                               <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#393e4e" />
                               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                           </Trigger>
                           
                           <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                               <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#007ACC" />
                               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                           </Trigger>
                       </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                   </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
       </Style>

CSharp:
public class Folder
{
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
}



 private void showfolders()
 {
   string getpath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path_);
   if (!Directory.Exists(getpath))
   {               
       lvFolders.ItemsSource = null;
   }
   else
   {
       var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(getpath).OrderBy(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime);
       ObservableCollection<Folder> folderList = new ObservableCollection<Folder>();
       foreach (var folder in folders)
       {
           var folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
           folderList.Add(new Folder
           {
               FolderName = folderInfo.Name,

               CreationTime = folderInfo.CreationTime
           });
       }
       lvFolders.ItemsSource = folderList;
   }
}

I want to customize the ListView's style to my desired look, including effects for mouse hover ， selection,header style, as well as the style of the scrollbar.

Take a look at ListView Styles and Templates. The ControlTemplate for ListViewItem contains a GridViewRowPresenter.
